# How to prevent multiple DB roundtrips for parents of has_many relations

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, errbit

I'm likely missing something here, but it seems like this is a performance oversight. I first noticed this when looking at the query logs of [Errbit](http://errbit.github.com/errbit/) and noticing hundreds of queries for the same objects.

It seems that all the children of a `has_many` relation don't have a reference back to their parent object after being loaded through the relation.  i.e. accessing `parent.children.map &:parent` will get the parent from the DB once for each `child` instead of being setup with the in-memory copy of `parent`

### Example:

Using a very simple `belongs_to` / `has_many` setup:

```ruby
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
  has_many :posts, :inverse_of => :person
end

class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :text
  belongs_to :person, :inverse_of => :posts
end
```

Then, in the Rails console, a simple demonstration:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.12)
[1] pry(main)> tom = Person.create(:name => 'Tom')
[2] pry(main)> tom.posts.create(:text => 'stuff')
[3] pry(main)> tom.posts.create(:text => 'other stuff')
[4] pry(main)> Person.first.posts.map {|post| post.person.object_id}
=> [50687740, 50719060]
```

**Note that last line**, each `person` reference points to a different ruby object. I'm using ruby's `object_id` attribute to highlight the fact that these are literally different objects and this requires two round-trips to the database.

**Why isn't the parent relation just a reference to the parent object** after loading through the has_many relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this is a known deficiency and adding this feature [is planned](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/2882#issuecomment-14679020) for version 4.0.

In the mean time, you can drastically reduce duplicated queries and improve performance by enabling the [Mongoid Identity Map](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/identity_map.html)